# Keep Getting “document cannot be autosaved” using Apple Pages 8.2

Tags: pages

I am trying to save a document using Apple Pages version 8.2 on Catalina. Every time I make change and try to save, I keep getting "this document cannot be autosaved" error. It was working just fine, but started acting up today. Has anyone else run into this error?

Comment: Can you please specify where you are trying to save e.g. on your iCloud folder, or on your Mac. It may be a simple iCloud authentication issue that needs a re-login

Comment: I am trying to save on my Mac.